# correlation between integers in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, associations, regression, correlation

I am interested to assess the relationship of the result of entrance exam to the exams results from the first semester - both variables are integers. I have calculated the Pearson correlation for these.

However, since my variables are integers the scatter point are not really scattered.

**Is there a better way to calculate and visualize the correlation? Or any other measure of their relationship?**

**What if my two integers are not distributed normally?**

**Is it a problem that they are not on the same scale ?** `final` is expressed as percentage and `entrance_exam` is a testscore from 0-15.

```
test_data <- data.frame("entrance_exam" = sample(0:15,200,replace=T), "final" = sample(0:100,200,replace=T))
str(test_data)
cor.test(entrance_exam,percentage)

ggplot(test_data, aes(x=entrance_exam, y=final)) + 
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method=lm, color="black")+
  # labs(title="Correlation between Diagnostic testscore and Percentage",
       # x= "Total testscore", y = "Percentage" )+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=15, face="bold", hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the normal distribution assumption is violated, you may use rank correlation test
(Spearman):  `cor.test(test_data$entrance_exam,test_data$final, m = 's')`
It returns a Spearman's `rho`, which you can interpret as if it was a Pearson's `r`.

There are transformations you could use for percentage value, but since Spearman correlation test ranks the data, it does not make any difference.

It becomes a problem when one of your axes are expressed as a discrete variables, in which cas you must use Kendall's `tau`.

see [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient)

Comment: thanks @Lokinou. Regarding the discrete variables shouldn't  the `entrance_exam` be considered a discrete variable? Students are graded on 15 point scale and the only possible values are 1,2,3...,15.

Comment: You can use both, `m = 'kendall"`. Depending on the people you address: people would usually compute a Spearman, but studies claim that Kendall is more conservative than Spearman (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3943/kendall-tau-or-spearmans-rho ). Kendall is really preferred when you have many tied (=same) ranks. Smaller scales (for example: 1-5) come with less ranks and more ties. If you want to address a broad audience, go for a popular method. For statisticians and math people, go for the most conservative solution. I would for myself calculate both and check mismatches.

Comment: I get two quite different value for S.rho =0.3 and K.tau=0.2. The normality assumption has been violated for both of my variables, but according to the CLT if the n>30 parametric tests can be used anyways. This is a dilema for me, my n>30 but the correlation coefficient are quite different. Which one should i report then?

Comment: You may use `ks.test()`or `shapiro.test()` (the latter being more conservative) to check your distribution, and thereby your normality assumption ; not CLT. Luckily for you Spearman and Kendall are non-parametric. In your case `rho=.3` and `tau=.2` are pretty much the same low correlation.

Comment: I have also calculated the Pearsons correlation, which yields 0.28. Somewhere I have seen an argument that the lack of difference between these correlation coefficients suggests that the data is normally distributed. However, Shapiro-Wilk test rejects normality. Does the lack of difference between the correlation coefficient have any meaning?

Comment: I don't have the knowledge ot answer this, I'm pretty sure opening a post on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ would help you get better advice.